# How to stretch image of Spinner?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a Spinner with only image inside.
Can I stretch the image all over the spinner?

[image]

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/country_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter

```
public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
{   
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) m_Contex.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);      
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.country_icon);
    icon.setImageResource(m_CountryImages.get(position));
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/country_icon"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

If its API 7 or lower use fill_parent instead match_parent. Also make sure, that the icon is properly stretched inside itself, and there is no unnecessary transparent bacground that makes icon larger than you actually need

Comment: Thanks you were right, I didn't noticed that the image has unnecessary transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

your image will stretch over the entire display area.